# Resize UIImage to fit device width

Tags: swift, uiimage

I need to fit an image as background in my swift 3 application. I set the background with this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg_sunrise")!)
```

Is there a way to make sure that the image fits the current device width and is not upscaled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you really want.

- If you need "aspect fit", you need to either drop your image into a UIImageView like emresancaktar provided. The issue with this  - and by your use of the view's backgroundColor you suggest this - is that you wish to put things **on top** of said UIImageView. This is complicating things.
- If you just need to scale to the view size with no regard to "aspect fit", you can use it's layer:

  ```
  view.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "bg_sunrise")?.cgImage
  ```
- Finally, if your like using a view's layer but do need "aspect fit", you'll need to work with a CGImage context, possibly using the UIImage.drawInRect() method after making some calculations. A quick search on "CALayer draw image aspect fit" yielded this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tomasbasham/10533743). It's a little old but there's a Swift version there. You can cobble what you need to return a CALayer instead of a UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

This little snippet will solve your problem. Have a nice coding.

```
var imageView : UIImageView
imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 70))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```